# Date field formatting as number in ESRI popup window

Tags: javascript, date, formatting, template, arcgis-state-government

We are using the [Park and Recreation Locator](http://solutions.arcgis.com/state-government/help/park-and-recreation-locator/) from ArcGIS for State Government and trying to put a date field into the popup info window.  The field is pulling the correct data, but it's formatting it as a number (JavaScript milliseconds) instead of a date.  There is a variable in the **config.js** file called `FormatDateAs` which has been set as a date according to ESRI's site `"MMM dd, yyyy"`, but has no discernible effect.  From experience with some of ESRI's other templates, I tried adding in fields to the `InfoPopupFieldsCollection` such as `isDate` or variations on `Format` but none worked.  ESRI's site has no additional documentation for formatting a date in this template.

We need the field to remain a date type in the database for future changes we have planned, so simply changing the fields to strings containing the pre-formatted dates won't work.  Does anyone know how we can get this field to format correctly in the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the formatting for the date attributes in your template using the built in support. The format is `${FIELD_NAME:FORMAT_FUNCTION_NAME(OPTION_A: value, OPTION_B: value)}`. So for dates you can use something like `${DATE:DateFormat}` or `${DATE:DateString}`. There are more options documented at the [format info window](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_formatinfowindow.html) help page. Hopefully you can find the correct place in the config to edit and get this to work.

Comment: This looked so promising, but unfortunately doesn't work.  The `DateFormat` and `DateString` options alone cause it to return an error message, and including the optional parameters makes the template interpret the whole thing as a string, not a variable.